# Can I use lapply to check for outliers in comparison to values from all listed tibbles?

Tags: r, lapply

My data is imported into R as a list of 60 tibbles each with 13 columns and 8 rows. I want to detect outliers defined as 2*sd by comparing each value in column "2" to the mean of all values of column "2" in the same row.

I know that I am on a wrong path with these lines, as I am not comparing the single values

```
lapply(list, function(x){
  if(x$"2">(mean(x$"2")) + (2*sd(x$"2"))||x$"2"<(mean(x$"2")) - (2*sd(x$"2"))) {}
  })
```

Also I was hoping to replace all values that are thus identified as outliers by the corresponding mean calculated from the 60 values in the same position as the outlier while keeping everything else, but I am also quite unsure how to do that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't added an example of your code so I've made a quick and simple example to demonstrate my answer. I think this would be much more straightforward logic if you first combine the list of tibbles into a single tibble. This allows you to do everything you want in a simple dplyr pipe, ultimately identifying outliers by 1's in the 'outlier' column:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble1 <- tibble(colA = c(seq(1,20,1), 150),
                  colB = seq(0.1,2.1,0.1),
                  id = 1:21)

tibble2 <- tibble(colA = c(seq(101,120,1), -150),
                  colB = seq(21,41,1),
                  id = 1:21)

# N.B. if you don't have an 'id' column or equivalent 
# then it makes it a lot easier if you add one
# The 'id' column is essentially shorthand for an index

tibbleList <- list(tibble1, tibble2)

joinedTibbles <- bind_rows(tibbleList, .id = 'tbl')

res <- joinedTibbles %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(meanA = mean(colA),
         sdA = sd(colA),
         lowThresh = meanA - 2*sdA,
         uppThresh = meanA + 2*sdA,
         outlier = ifelse(colA > uppThresh | colA < lowThresh, 1, 0))
```

Comment: `map_dfr` is redundant. Just `bind_rows(tibbleList, .id = 'tbl')`